# Grunt notify not running

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to get desktop notifications working with Grunt, and have installed [Grunt notify](https://github.com/dylang/grunt-notify). As per the instructions, I have also installed "Growl" (I'm on Windows 7), and also included the line `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-notify');` in my Gruntfile, however desktop notifications are not showing at all.

Am I missing something? The Grunt Notify page seems to imply that adding in the loadNpmTasks line is the only addition needed in my gruntfile for it to work with default options.

Here is my Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({

    less: {
      development: {
        options: {
            paths: ["less"],
            compress: true,
            strictMath: true,
            sourceMap: false,
            sourceMapFilename: 'css/styles.css.map',
            sourceMapRootpath: '/'
        },
        files: {
            "css/styles.css": "css/style.less"
        }
      }
    },

    uglify: {
      my_target: {
        files: {
          'js/custom.min.js': ['js/custom.js']
        }
      }
    },

    watch: {
      compile: {
          files: ['**/*.php', 'css/**/*.less', 'js/**/*.js', '!js/custom.min.js'],
          tasks: ['less', 'uglify'],
          options: { 
            atBegin: true,
            livereload: true
          }
      }
    }

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-notify');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less']);

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum... I never used the grunt-notify plugin, but as the doc says, this plugin shows warning or errors of your tasks. So if your task run successfully, you shouldn't be notified.
If you wan't custom messages on success too, you'll have to add the optionnal messages.

To be sure that the problem isn't an effect of a bad installation, try to run the simple gruntfile shown as example on the plugin's page.
If it works, you should consider my first explanation and add a custom message on success.

*[**Edit**: try to run your task with the attribute `-v` to have a verbose run. As specified in the doc, it will write logs if there is errors with the plugin]*

This is the grunt-notify example file (from the plugin's doc) :

```
grunt.initConfig({
  // This is optional!
  notify_hooks: {
    options: {
      enabled: true,
      max_jshint_notifications: 5, // maximum number of notifications from jshint output
      title: "Project Name", // defaults to the name in package.json, or will use project directory's name
      success: false, // whether successful grunt executions should be notified automatically
      duration: 3 // the duration of notification in seconds, for `notify-send only
    }
  }
});

// Load the task
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-notify');

// This is required if you use any options.
grunt.task.run('notify_hooks');
```